# No Startup folder in Microsoft Office for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2011

I'm trying to save a new default worksheet in Excel for Mac 2011. Instructions say to save it in the Startup folder at this location:

```
/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office/Startup/Excel
```

There is no Startup folder here. Instructions on the Microsoft website do not include the 2011 version. Is this a problem with my installation, Excel for Mac 2011, or something else?

Comment: Try creating the directory and file and let us know if it works, sometimes the installation skips the creation of directories such as this if they are empty by default.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Excel for Mac uses a default workbook, but you can use your own.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/changing-the-excel-default-workbook-and/e727bb2a-da12-4ee9-8224-088700c20b3e)

Your Startup folder by default is:

`HD:Applications:Microsoft Office 2011:Office:Startup:Excel`

(You can change this in Preferences if you want).

- Create your work with all the settings you want.
- Save the workbook as a template (.xltm) with a name of `Workbook` (without quotes)
- Navigate to your Startup folder
- Select the file and choose Get Info
- Delete the extension (.xltm) on the file.

Excel will now use that workbook as your default workbook.

Comment: Just confirmed that this does work (thanks!), but don't forget to re-start Excel.  It is called the `Startup` folder for a reason.  And you do have to remove the extension as described - simply deleting it in the Finder just "hides" the extension, it doesn't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the file linkCreation.dotm
From my HD:Applications:Microsoft Office 2011:Office:Startup:Word folder and it fixed the problem